# Answer for questions number 10 udacity Android Beginner coffee break challenge?

Tags: android, xml

I am a beginner of android development. I just want to ask what's wrong with my answer.

[image: Here's the question]

Here are the answers that I tried:

1. 100 
   ~ (since Menu textview has already taken the 200dp height there's only 400dp left. the viewgroup has a total of 4 weights and chai tea view has 1. So what I did is (400*1)/4 = 100
2. 150
   ~ I disregarded the 200dp of the menu text view and did the equation (600*1)/4

Well I got it wrong. I hope you can help me fully understand.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mention the unit "dp". The complete answer should have been "100dp". Though congratulations your calculations to arrive to that answer is correct.